# Проблема с необходимостью драйвера для виртуального COM-порта, Linux

Tags: linux, debian, usb, драйвер, com-порт

Возникла проблема такого типа: мне было поручено проверить работоспособность стенда, для которого было ранее разработано тестовое ПО на ОС Linux, предположительно на Debian 7. Суть в том, что работа со стендом осуществляется через  USB-порт, но при подключении система видит  **ttyACM0**, а не **ttyUSB0**, как было изначально заявлено в конфигурациях ПО (PID и VID видит верные). Также было обнаружено в старых записях, что программа использует виртуальный COM-порт, основанный на USB. Саму программу менять нельзя, можно, но не желательно менять конфигурации. Но при попытке задать другое имя порта в конфигурациях (**ttyACM0** вместо **ttyUSB0**) ситуация с программой не меняется, она всё так же не может подключиться к стенду.
Было решено вручную создать виртуальный **COM-порт**.
Первой идеей было использовать *usbserial* :

```
modprobe usbserial vendor=0x0483 product=0xf125
```

Никакой реакции в терминале не произошло. И программа также не видит стенда.
Вторая идея – использовать *Virtual Serial Port Driver*  также не увенчалась успехом, поскольку VSPD просто отказывается ставиться.
Третья идея была переименовать  сам файл **ttyACM0**. Решено было сделать через *rules*. 
С помощью команды:

```
Udevadm info -a –n ttyACM0
```

Было получено

```
Kernel==”ttyACM0”
SUBSYSTEM=”tty”
Driver==””
```

На основе этого написал правило:

```
KERNEL ==”ttyACM0”, SUBSYSTEM==”tty”, name = “ttyUSB0”
```

Но после перезагрузки, как и ожидалось снова ничего не изменилось.
И тут у меня закрылись сомнения, что возможно для этого стенда нужен свой какой-то драйвер, а я такого просто не имею. Есть ли возможность мне точно узнать о его необходимости ?

Comment: *проверить работоспособность стенда* - судя по вопросу, скорее "обеспечить работоспособность", не так ли? *предположительно на Debian 7* - это ПО поставляется отдельно от системы или как, где производилось приемочное тестирование? Что там установлено сейчас?

Comment: Да, обеспечить работоспособность, По поставляется вместе , ОС. Никакой приемки по операционной системе не проводится ,только по контрольной сумме программного обеспечения.

Comment: В принципе, ttyUSB и ttyACM не сильно различаются и зависят от модели USB-to-COM конвертора. Так что попробуйте поиграться с настройками порта (скорость etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как выяснилось, драйвер уже существовал в установленном виде, но не имел действия так как его перекрывал другой драйвер *cdc-acm*.
Чтобы это исправить его нужно выгрузить из ядра, а затем загрузить необходимый:
`# modprobe -r cdc-acm`
`# modprobe usbserial vendor=0x0483 product=0xf125`
И заветный **ttyUSB0** появляется. Стоит отметить, что это требуется вводить при каждом переподключении USB. Чтобы это не делать, как вариант, можно удалить сам драйвер *cdc-acm*.